# Bootsrap dropdown hover menu is not responsive

Tags: html, css, navbar

[Website before window is minimised.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apiVT.png)
[Website after window is minimised.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jsb0M.png) I have a bootstrap hover dropdown menu that works as expected, except when the browser window is minimised, the menu does not display at all. I have overridden some of the styling with my own css.

Any help or pointers of where I am going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```html
<div class="bs-example">
    <nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="container" align="center">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle disabled" data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Text<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
     <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle disabled" data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Text<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
     <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS: 
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
    .bs-example{

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
 .bs-example{
  background-color: black !important;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  position: fixed;
    }
 .navbar{
  background-color: black !important;
 }
 .nav > li > a{
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white !important;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 40px;
 }
 .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
 }
 .dropdown-menu{
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white !important;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
 }
 .dropdown a {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: black !important;
 }
```

Comment: If you can provide a screenshot for your webpage before and after minimizing the window it will be helpful for us

Comment: @HamedAdil I've added screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to get a responsive dropdown hover menu (I read somewhere that Bootstrap is limited in enabling the menu to be responsive when a hover is trying to be incorporated).
Instead, I used a menu in which the user has to click on the parent tab.

```css
.nav {
 padding-left: 3cm !important;
}

.navbar {
    font-family: Open Sans !important;
 font-size: 18px !important;
 padding: 20px 42px !important;
 color: #FF0000 !important;
 background-color: black !important;
 width: 100% !important;
 position: fixed !important;
 top: 0 !important;
 z-index: 50 !important;
 padding-bottom: 11px !important;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand{
 color: white !important;
 font-size: 22px !important;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
 color: white !important;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a {
 font-family: Open Sans !important;
 font-size: 18px !important;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 42px !important;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: white !important;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
        margin-top: 2px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: black !important;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus, .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
    color: white !important;
 font-size: 18px !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: black !important;
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Baby Daddy</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Pregnancy and Birth<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="supportpartner.html">Support Your Partner</a></li>
            <li><a href="labour.html">Labour</a></li>
            <li><a href="complications.html">Complications</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Mental Health<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="postpartum.html">Postpartum Depression</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="paternityleave.html">Paternity Leave</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="register.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if you have imported bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js, so i would suggest you try to import those two first and normally it should be fixed

Comment: I have all of these at the top of my file:                                                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-dropdownhover.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

It is collapsed, you need a **toggler** to trigger between the different states (show and hide). In the following i gave a brief example what i mean. The toggler is the "hamburger" icon (the three solid lines on the right). It only appears on smaller devices i.e. window sizes, so if you reduce your window you will see the toggler. You can find more informations here:

1. For [Bootstrap 3.3.7](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar)
2. For [Bootstrap >=4.0](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Navbar Toggler</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
          </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Your Brand</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Best regards,
Sven